# XPath to LINQ Conversion

Tags: c#, xpath, linq-to-xml

Working with an XML file in C#, I'm trying to convert an XPath query to LINQ and I don't know how to achieve the last section:

XPath:

```
variable.XPathSelectElements("procedures/menu[@id='value']/procedure[@id]")
```

LINQ:

```
from el in variable.Descendants("procedures").Descendants("menu")
where el.Element("id").Value == "value"
```

### How do I achieve the /procedure[@id] section?

I've modified to your suggestion @Jon but I seem to be making a simple error here that I cannot resolve.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("procedures.xml");
var query = doc.Elements("procedures")
               .Elements("menu")
               .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("id") == "value")
               .Elements("procedure").Where(x => x.Attribute("id") != null);

public List<string> commands = new List<string>();
foreach (XElement procedure in query) {
    commands.Add(procedure.Attribute("id"));
}
```

Comment: @Chris, your XPath expression (and @Jon's translated LINQ query) returns `<procedure>` elements, not `id` attributes. Maybe you're looking for `foreach (XElement procedure in query) { commands.Add(procedure.Attribute("id")); }`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, yes, that is what I was hoping to achieve.  Unfortunately, I'm still generating a compile error on the foreach line.

Comment: @Chris, and that error is ?... :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, all three errors reference the same line (foreach)  
error CS1519: Invalid token 'foreach' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
error CS1002: ; expected
error CS1519: Invalid token ')' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: That's a syntax error. It looks like the code you posted resides in the class body itself, outside of a method, which is illegal (the `public` keyword gives it away, I'm only seeing it now for some reason). Your `foreach` loop should be located in one of your class' methods.

Comment: Yes, it was quite obvious in retrospect :(, fixed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`/procedure[@id]` selects all "procedure" elements which have an "id" attribute. However, I don't believe you should be using `Descendants` in this case. I believe your query should really be:

```
 variable.Elements("procedures")
         .Elements("menu")
         .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("id") == "value")
         .Elements("procedure")
         .Where(x => x.Attribute("id") != null);
```

EDIT: There's a simpler way of getting the command IDs into a list:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("procedures.xml");
var commands = doc.Elements("procedures")
                  .Elements("menu")
                  .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("id") == "value")
                  .Elements("procedure")
                  .Where(x => x.Attribute("id") != null)
                  .Select(x => x.Attribute("id").Value)
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: I implemented your solution but I'm having mistakes elsewhere.  I edited the question to include a more complete code.

Comment: @Chris: You need to cast the attribute to `string` or use the Value property. I've edited my answer with an alternative approach to your foreach loop.